# How to kill a sprite with multiple hits?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to make a shooter game with different enemy and I'm trying to kill a boss with multiple hits but I can't see how I can do it. Can anyone explain it to me please?

Comment: Inherit from `SKSpriteNode`, add a property (e.g. `health`) and init it with desired value. After each hit decrement the health and check if it became zero (which means boss has been killed).

Comment: Give the boss userData.

Comment: tried to do that can you check  please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to update my answer i just created a variable who represent life of the boss

```
var vieboss = 10
```

and i also created  a function who setup the kill of the boss or not

```
func bossdead(projectile: Projectile!,boss1 : Boss!) {

    print("Hit boss")
    projectile.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    projectile.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0
    projectile.removeFromParent()

    vieboss1 -= 1

    if (vieboss1 == 0) {

        monstersDestroyed += 10
        boss1.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        boss1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0
        boss1.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

and call the function bossdead when the projectile hit the boss

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're keeping track of the boss's health inside of `projectileDidCollideWithBoss`, but you're setting the boss's health to 10 every time you call the function (which means the lowest it will ever get is 9). You need to keep track of `monsterhp` outside of the function and just decrement it each time you call that collision function.  You could do as   Dan Karbaye suggested and make the boss a subclass of SKSpriteNode with a health property. You could also make monsterhp a property of the scene, but your scene will start to get messy fast if you need to do that kind of thing a lot, so subclassing SKSpriteNode would be a better solution in the long term.

Comment: i added the class boss and called it on my function could you explain me how i can use the health property please?

Comment: You would give the boss a health property like.  When you decrement it in your function, you would do something like boss.health -= 1.  When you check in your function if the boss should be dead, you would do something like if boss.health <= 0 { boss.removeFromParent() } (This is all assuming boss is a subclass of SKSpriteNode).  Looks like the reason you can't easily access the his HP is there isn't a property for it on your class. You want something like var health: Int and then set the value in your initializer.

Comment: thanks you or your reply i tried to do that whit my function killABoss and my global var hpboss but i still got some issues and the boss still die after one hit can you do you know how i can fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

**Removal**:
Recommended common method is: when you detect that a node should be removed (from collision detection code) add it to a removal list, and remove every object in this list either in `didFinishUpdate` or `update`.

**Data management**:
Now if you need to attach some data to a node, subclass its type and add appropriate properties and methods.